# How to notify huge number of followers?

Tags: database-design, notifications, application-design

Assume one person have a really many followers. 
This person post a story and app should notify all followers. If number of followers not too big we can just send email when user clicked submit button.

But how will you implement notification system if some people will have thouthands of followers?

Comment: If you are going to send emails, you still need to send emails. I would recommend separating the phases -- 1) "queue a discrete event" (this can be really fancy with message queues or server agents, etc, but can also be done by adding a "need updates" to a queue table or have a some method per table of detecting that new changes are in since the last check time) 2) Either as a result of a message being queued (e.g. if using a message queue) or periodically (in a background process) go through and process the pending notifications -- batch up and send emails, clear queues/flags, etc.

Comment: Form a new religion and ask its angels to bypass any and all spam filters and deliver the notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than emailing everyone, look for a publish/subscribe method.

For example, if you made the updates available via an RSS feed, people could subscribe to the feed to receive updates. You just display the update in the RSS feed and it is consumed by anyone who is "listening" to that feed.

http://www.whatisrss.com/